# possibility to use parse_str on variables

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So I made a post related to me wanting to have my JSON file look like this:

```
 {
  "main_object": {
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "getExerciseTitle": "asd",
    "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord": ["asd"],
    "Syllablescounter": ["ASDasd", ""]
  }
}
```

instead of this:

```
 {
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "formData": "language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=test"
  }
}
```

people recommended me to use `parse_st` to make my JSON look like the first piece of code, however my question (the reason I made a new post was because they gave a great tip, but never responded to it unfortunately and I wasn't really sure if I could edit my post regarding to a whole new subject basically), is it possible to use this directly on variables? they gave me this piece of code:

```
const result = "language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test";
const parsed = queryString.parse(result);
```

as you can see it directly takes the variable + the value given to it, but I was wondering: I will always insert new data etc, so how can I apply it so it will always target the variable that could possibly change (instead of litterly writing `language=nl_NL` for example) I came to notice that whenever I insert the piece `data: {id: getUrlParameter('id')` in my ajax call, it will make my JSON look like the second one (but I do get my ID send), but whenever I take that piece out of it it will show up like the first one but it won't increment any longer. the complete ajax call looks like this:

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
              url: 'saveJson.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {id: getUrlParameter('id'), formData: $('#my_form').serialize()},
              dataType: 'json',
          }).done(function (response) {

          });
 });
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: why don't you already `formData: $('#my_form').serializeArray()`? Then there is no hussle of deserializing...  https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Yeah, tried it, at first I thought it worked, but it totally trips to oblivion and makes my stuff reproduce three tims etc.